# How can we navigate seperate screen using CarouselSlider flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-go-router, carousel-slider

I'm using go router package for routing.And trying to open seperate pages with the id when clicking on the page

my function inside my homepage.dart

```
Widget buildImage(String urlImage, String title, int price, double padding,
        int index, String id) => 
    GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        context.go(); **//this is returning context is undefined**
      },
      child: Container(
        child: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0),
          child: Container(
             ...
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

I want to be able to use context to navigate to my page with the id.